# Can I actually nuke anything?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

After a certain point in the plot, you get the ability to build nukes, supposedly as a deterrent against other people invading your FOBs. Around this point, you also get the ability to completely ignore other people's nukes and invade them anyway.

Is there any circumstance under which one of these nukes would actually go off? Can I actually nuke people who mess with me? Or perhaps sneak into wherever a rival is keeping their nukes and rig one to blow?

Answer (score 2):

Nukes cannot be used in-game, against players or as part of the story.

However, having a Nuke (at least one), prevents players with less than 150,000 Heroism from launching attacks against your FOBs.

They also get you an achievement, if you're into that sort of thing!

Comment: Building a nuke also lowers your heroism by 30k.

Comment: [it also contributes massively to your demon points](http://it%20also%20contributes%20massively%20to%20your%20[demon%20points]%20[1:http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/238502/what-changes-when-i-build-a-nuclear-weapon/238503#238503)